# Deciding key-value pairs for Roman Numeral Converter

Tags: javascript

Every solution I've found uses the following object.

```
function converter(num) {
     var romanKeys =
     {M:1000,CM:900,D:500,CD:400,C:100,XC:90,L:50,XL:40,X:10,IX:9,V:5,IV:4,I:1}
```

When attempting the problem myself, I wasn't too sure which roman numerals were redundant when constructing the object. Procedurally, how do we arrive to this object? e.g How do I know that
"VI: 6" is unnecessary but "IV: 4" is?

Comment: You don't need `IV` either. I've implemented it without entries like this. Having these irregular entries just makes code much more elegant, basically a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

When a symbol appears after a larger (or equal) symbol it is added
Example: VI = V + I = 5 + 1 = 6
Example: LXX = L + X + X = 50 + 10 + 10 = 70

But if the symbol appears before a larger symbol it is subtracted
Example: IV = V − I = 5 − 1 = 4
Example: IX = X − I = 10 − 1 = 9

I can be placed before V (5) and X (10) to make 4 and 9.

X can be placed before L (50) and C (100) to make 40 and 90.

C can be placed before D (500) and M (1000) to make 400 and 900.

When you are scanning a roman number you are looking from left to right at each symbol and if it appears before a larger symbol, you take them together, do the substraction and add it to the result, then move to the symbol after them. Otherwise you take a single symbol and add its value to the result and move to the next symbol.

For example for XIV:

```
1) result = 0
2) X < I => result += 10 (result = 10)
3) I < V => result += (5-1) (result = 14)
```

Note that if you are using that mapping, you only need the combinations where the second symbol is greater than the first one for which the substraction rule applies, as noted above (CM, CD, XC, XL, IX, IV).

Having something like XI in that mapping would give you a wrong result. For XIV you will have XI (11) + V (5) = 16, not X (10) + IV (4) = 14.

Comment: The question, as I see it, is "why put `IV`/`IX`/others in the mapping at all? Can we not do it with just the base digits?"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't see it like that, but if that is the case - it is possible to implement with just base digits, or even without using that object at all, but it makes the algorithm more complex (need to make comparations / substractions, ...). For example if you use only base digits and you find a "I" you need to look at the next symbol then decide if you need to add 1, 4 or 9, while if you already have them in the object you don't need to do that since IX and IV are checked before I (In the JS implementation I found they rely on keys being ordered, which I think is not guaranteed).

Comment: "which I think is not guaranteed" - depends on the language. Not sure about javascript, but in ruby hashes maintain insertion order. And in, say, go it's intentionally randomized.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was referring specifically to a javascript implementation I found that seemed to be what was mentioned in the question (https://codingnconcepts.com/tools/number-to-roman/). Javascript has a Map object that guarantees key order (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). In this doc they say: "Although the keys of an ordinary Object are ordered now, this was not always the case, and the order is complex. As a result, it's best not to rely on property order.".

Comment: Ah, I missed that you're talking about JS specifically. My bad.